# Query about a given function's use in the code

Tags: c++, testing

i'm following this tutorial and they give us this code to test the function isLowerVowel:

```
#include <iostream>

bool isLowerVowel(char c, bool yIsVowel)
{
    switch (c)
    {
    case 'a':
    case 'e':
    case 'i':
    case 'o':
    case 'u':
        return true;
    case 'y':
        return (yIsVowel ? true : false);
    default:
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    std::cout << isLowerVowel('a',false) << "\n";
    std::cout << isLowerVowel('a',true) << "\n";

    std::cout << isLowerVowel('q',false) << "\n";
    std::cout << isLowerVowel('q',true) << "\n";

    std::cout << isLowerVowel('y',false) << "\n";
    std::cout << isLowerVowel('y',true) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I dont understand what the use of yIsVowel is for, shouldnt just testing isLowerVowel be enough? Sorry i asked them but got no replies

Comment: Y is sometimes considered a vowel. https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/why-y-is-sometimes-a-vowel-usage

Comment: The question really has more to do with the English language, and not really about programming.  I have to admit that it is a rather unique way to get to the question as to why a `y` is special.

Comment: Did you run the program and look at the output? The program is designed so that the output explains the use of `yIsVowel`.

Comment: Ah thank you all, so 'y' can be either a consonant or a vowel. That totally clears things up!

Answer (score 0):

> I dont understand what the use of yIsVowel is for, shouldnt just testing isLowerVowel be enough?

If you were to use the `isLowerVowel` fuction to implement the `isLowerVowel` function you would have recursion. It is unclear how this recursion should be terminated.

`yIsVowel` appears to be used to set whether y is a vowel or not.

Comment: `return (yIsVowel ? true : false);` can be simply written as `return yIsVowel;`

Comment: However, if you take a look at the link Retired Ninja's posted, they have considered `'y'` as a vowel **and** a consonant. I think that is what they are trying to do

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 The link says that y is sometimes considered a vowel. That is probably why there is an argument  `yIsVowel`. I think that OP doesn't know what they're trying to do because they don't understand why the argument is needed.

Comment: Yes.  Maybe the OP knows exactly what the code does, but wants to know why it's being done.  Probably not familiar with the oddity of `y` in the English language as a consonant *and* a vowel.